# How to link votes of answers to votes of a user?

Tags: python, html, css, django, web

I'm working on a Django project that users can ask and answer the questions. meanwhile users can vote answers like stackoverflow answers. now I wanna link vote numbers of answers and votes of a user. for example user A answered a question and his answer gets 10 votes, again user A answer another question and gets 5 votes. now votes of this user should be 15.
How can I do this? any ideas?
Thanks in advance.
This is my Model:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(msignup, related_name="uanswer")
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Answer'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Answers'
    ordering = ('-is_accepted', '-votes', 'create_date',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.description

def accept(self):
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=self.question)
    for answer in answers:
        answer.is_accepted = False
        answer.save()
    self.is_accepted = True
    self.save()
    self.question.has_accepted_answer = True
    self.question.save()

def calculate_votes(self):
    up_votes = Activity.objects.filter(activity_type=Activity.UP_VOTE,
                                       answer=self.pk).count()
    down_votes = Activity.objects.filter(activity_type=Activity.DOWN_VOTE,
                                         answer=self.pk).count()
    self.votes = up_votes - down_votes
    self.save()
    return self.votes
```

And This is my view:

```
def vote(request):
    answer_id = request.POST['answer']
    answer = Answer.objects.get(pk=answer_id)
    vote = request.POST['vote']
    userID = request.session.get('mainSession', 0)
    user = msignup.objects.get(id=userID)
    activity = Activity.objects.filter(
    Q(activity_type=Activity.UP_VOTE) | Q(activity_type=Activity.DOWN_VOTE),
        user=user, answer=answer_id)
    if activity:
        activity.delete()
    if vote in [Activity.UP_VOTE, Activity.DOWN_VOTE]:
        activity = Activity(activity_type=vote, user=user, answer=answer_id)
        activity.save()
    return HttpResponse(answer.calculate_votes())
```

Comment: Did you read the [topic guide on aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/)? Hint: Sum the votes for all answers provided by user.

Comment: Thanks. but I want sum the votes for all answers the user get. for example one of his answers gets 10 and another gets 5, now the user has 15 votes and can shown in user profile section.

Comment: Look at @darthvader1996 answer. That's what I said, only he spelled it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query all votes mapped via the foreign key to the particular user and then sum over them using [django's aggregation mechanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
#user_obj is an instance of the user whose votes you want to sum over

sum_of_votes = Answer.objects.filter(user=user_obj).aggregate(Sum('votes'))
```